# Is it possible to use app.use inside the if else statement in Express

Tags: node.js, express, express-rate-limit

I want to check whether user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in I want to restrict the access. I've used express-rate-limit and setting the rate limit inside if statement but its not working.

It works fine I put that outside if

Any suggestions?

````
    console.log("Routing");
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    if(req.cookies['session-token']){
        res.locals.isLoggedIn = true
      }else{
        console.log("Enter into rate limit");
        rateLimit({
          windowMs: 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 12 hour duration in milliseconds
          max: 1,
          message: "You exceeded 100 requests in 12 hour limit!",
          headers: true,
        })
        res.locals.isLoggedIn = false
      }
      next()
})```
````

Comment: My guess is that the `if(req.cookies['session-token'])` condition is resolving to truthy even when you think it shouldn't...

Comment: Not its not because I can see the `Enter into rate limit` in my log

Comment: Gotchya. And you're positive it works outside the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes you’re right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is going to create a new instance of express-rate-limit for each request where the user is not logged in. This won't work because each instance will only see that single request, so it will never trigger the limit.

Instead you should have a single global instance and use the `skip` option to have it skip requests from logged in users:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(req.cookies['session-token']){
    res.locals.isLoggedIn = true
  } else {
    res.locals.isLoggedIn = false
  }
  next()
});

app.use(rateLimit({
  windowMs: 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 12 hour duration in milliseconds
  max: 100,
  message: "You exceeded 100 requests in 12 hour limit!",
  headers: true,
  skip: (req, res) => res.locals.isLoggedIn, // skip all logged in requests
});
```

---

Disclaimer: I am the author of express-rate-limit